# Bootstrap Backbone.js models from django model with TastyPie

Tags: json, django, backbone.js, tastypie, bootstrapping

I am using **Django + TastyPie + Backbone.js**. I am trying to figure out how to bootstrap the initial data for the models on the first request, instead of fetching them after the initial page load as recommended here: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap

There are two issues--one is trying to load a single Django model and the other is trying to serialize a queryset.

As an example, I have a variable called `user` in the context which is a Django User and represents the current user who is logged in.

I do not want to do this:

```
var curUser = new App.Models.User({id: 1});
curUser.fetch();
```

and cause another request to the server, since I already have the user model loaded.

I want to boostrap this data into a Backbone model like:

```
var curUser = new App.Models.User({{user|json}});
```

(similar to [How to load bootstrapped models of backbone in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195361/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-of-backbone-in-django), but I do not want to do a special case on each view converting everything to json)

where I have created a custom template filter to convert to json

```
def json(object):
    """Return json string for object or queryset.    
    """
    if isinstance(object, QuerySet):
        return mark_safe(serialize('json', object))
    if isinstance(object, Model):
        object = object.to_dict()
    return mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(object))

register.filter('json', json)
```

The issue is if I seralize a django model, I get something that looks like this:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "auth.user", "fields": {"username": "user@gmail.com", "first_name": "Jeremy", "last_name": "Keeshin", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": false, "is_staff": false, "last_login": "2013-07-15T22:31:02", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "passwordhash", "email": "user@gmail.com", "date_joined": "2012-06-14T00:59:18"}}]'
```

What I really want is the json representation to match up with the api that I've defined using TastyPie:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    """A resource for the User model."""

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        authorization = Authorization()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'id']
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
            'email': ALL,
            'first_name': ALL,
            'last_name': ALL
        }
```

Here I only get a few fields passed back, not all of them when I serialize the model. I know Django lets you serialize only certain fields, but those fields are set on a per model basis, and I wouldn't want to include that call on every view.

I see a similar answer here [Django Serialize Queryset to JSON to construct RESTful response with only field information and id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431580/django-serialize-queryset-to-json-to-construct-restful-response-with-only-field), but this requires writing this call on every view.

My current solution is adding a method `to_dict` monkeypatched onto the User model

```
def to_dict(self):
    """Return a subset of fields as a dictionary."""
    return {
        'id': self.id,
        'first_name': self.first_name,
        'last_name': self.last_name,
        'email': self.email
    }
```

because this is easy to serialize. Additionally a django model cannot be serialized (not in a list of one) by itself, only querysets can be serialized.

I imagine lots of people are figuring out good ways to bootstrap their django model data into backbone models upon the initial page load (especially when working with TastyPie), but I haven't figured out a reasonable way to do this.

With querysets, there is additionally much more django info passed along, and I am trying to figure out a way to have the serialization match the output from the TastyPie api.

Does anyone have best practices to boostrap django models and querysets into backbone models?

**Update:**

I have changed my json filter to use TastyPie bundles like

```
from core.api import UserResource
from core.api import UserProfileResource
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer


def json(object):
    """Return json string for object or queryset."""

    TYPE_TO_RESOURCE = {
        'User': UserResource,
        'UserProfile': UserProfileResource
    }

    Resource = TYPE_TO_RESOURCE[object.__class__.__name__]

    r = Resource()
    bundle = r.build_bundle(object)
    r.full_dehydrate(bundle)
    s = Serializer()
    return mark_safe(s.serialize(bundle, 'application/json'))
```

Source: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views

This seems to be closer, work with single models, stay DRY with which fields I want that I have listed in TastyPie, but does not handle multiple models yet. I'm also not sure if it is problematic to have this in a filter.

**Update**

Also use this: https://gist.github.com/1568294/4d4007edfd98ef2536db3e02c1552fd59f059ad8

```
def json(object):
    """Return json string for object or queryset."""

    TYPE_TO_RESOURCE = {
        'User': UserResource,
        'UserProfile': UserProfileResource,
    }

    if isinstance(object, QuerySet):
        Resource = TYPE_TO_RESOURCE[object[0].__class__.__name__]
        r = Resource()

        bundles = [r.build_bundle(model) for model in object]
        bundle = [r.full_dehydrate(b) for b in bundles]

    elif isinstance(object, Model):
        Resource = TYPE_TO_RESOURCE[object.__class__.__name__]
        r = Resource()
        bundle = r.build_bundle(object)
        r.full_dehydrate(bundle)
    else:
        mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(object))

    s = Serializer()
    return mark_safe(s.serialize(bundle, 'application/json'))
```